# I try to access a route from my controller and it returns a 404 error instead of returning the entity in a JSON with POSTMAN

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, postman, dto

I try to access a route from my controller and it returns a 404 error instead of returning the entity in a JSON with POSTMAN

This is my controller

```
package com.main.CitaMedica.Controller;

import com.main.CitaMedica.DTO.CitaDTO;
import com.main.CitaMedica.DTO.MedicoDTO;
import com.main.CitaMedica.DTO.PacienteDTO;
import com.main.CitaMedica.Service.CitaService;
import com.main.CitaMedica.Service.MedicoService;
import com.main.CitaMedica.Service.PacienteService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/citas")
public class CitaController {
    @Autowired CitaService citaService;
    @Autowired MedicoService medicoService;
    @Autowired PacienteService pacienteService;

    @GetMapping("mostrarTodos")
    public ResponseEntity<CitaDTO> showCitas(){
        List<CitaDTO> citas = citaService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity(citas, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("mostrarUno/{citaID}")
    public ResponseEntity<CitaDTO> showCita(@PathVariable("citaID") int citaID){
        CitaDTO cita = citaService.findById(citaID);
        return new ResponseEntity(cita,HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    /*
    @GetMapping("mostrar/porFecha/{fecha}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cita> showCitaFechaHora(@PathVariable("fecha")Date fecha){
        List<Cita> cita = citaService.findByFechaHora(fecha);
        return new ResponseEntity(cita,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
     */

    @PostMapping("create")
    public ResponseEntity<CitaDTO> crearCita(){
        MedicoDTO medico = medicoService.findById(5);
        PacienteDTO paciente = pacienteService.findById(3);
        CitaDTO cita = new CitaDTO();
        cita.setMedico(medico);
        cita.setPaciente(paciente);
        cita.setFechaHora(new Date());
        cita.setMotivoCita("Prueba");
        citaService.save(cita);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("update/{citaID}")
    public ResponseEntity<CitaDTO> actualizarCita(@PathVariable("citaID") int citaID){
        CitaDTO cita = citaService.findById(citaID);
        cita.setMotivoCita("Enfermedad");
        citaService.save(cita);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("delete/{citaID}")
    public ResponseEntity<CitaDTO> delete(@PathVariable("citaID") int citaID){
        citaService.delete(citaID);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And this is the error that POSTMAN gives me when I try to access that route and I have the server started by port 8090

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-02-06T17:00:50.592+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/citas/mostrarTodos"
}
```

Before it worked for me and it returned all the data when I did not have DTO and MapperStructure but since I have implemented it now in all the routes it gives me that

Ask me for any information

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Unmitigated It didn't work for me :(

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I used this example -> ´´´@GetMapping("mostrarTodos")
     public ResponseEntity<CitaDTO> showCitas(){
         List<CitaDTO> citas = CitasService.findAll();
         return new ResponseEntity(appointments, HttpStatus.OK);
     }´´´

Comment: Please reread the link in my comment and provide what’s described there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Cuando accedo a esta ruta "/citas/mostrarTodos" en POSTMAN me sale el error 404 que mencioné anteriormente, cuando antes si me funcionaba. Todo los controladores me funcionaban hasta que intenté usar DTOS y mappers y ahora me devuelve el error 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding @Mapper(componentModel="spring") in all mappers it was my mistake